# align-content not working Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

```css
.row {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col2 {
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col1">
      Text
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col2">
      <p>
      Home
      </p>
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ez68c5mr/

align-content: flex-end not working IE 11. I want to justify the col-2 line to the right. 
align-items: flex-end is not doing what I want.

align-items: flex-end like this.

```
                 Home
Lorem ipsum dolor sit
```

I want this. But align-content does not work in IE.

```
           Home
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit
```

Comment: Try adding `display: -ms-flexbox` in addition to `display: flex;`.

Comment: You may also have to add `-ms-flex-align: end;`, or `align-items: flex-end;` as well.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett not working :/

Comment: Try `-ms-flex-pack: end` or `-ms-flex-line-pack: end` ?

Comment: Yeah, I kind of had a feeling it might not. Apparently IE has had all sorts of problems with flexbox throughout the years, and there are almost too many "fixes" that either don't work, or don't work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution I could find was to wrap your content in a `<div>` and to set your flexbox container to `align-items: flex-end`.

Here's [a community-curated list of flexbox issues and cross-browser workarounds for them](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs) (that might help you in your current project).

```css
.row {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col2 {
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* align-content: flex-end; */
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col1">Text</div>
    <div class="col-6 col2">
      <div class="ie-fix">
        <p>Home</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this when use flex-box => multiple line, IE11

after add `align-items: flex-start` for the container. the issue seems fixed